# What integer does DateTime.CompareTo actually return?

Tags: c#, datetime, compareto

I have been looking for an answer for some time now, but nowhere could I actually find it.

I was especially looking at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compareto.aspx). There it says that the `CompareTo` method returns an integer indicating if it is earlier, the same, or later. I understand the use of it and I understand that for earlier times the integer is negative, for the same it is 0 etc.

But what is this integer? Does it return the difference in seconds, milliseconds, ticks, or maybe nothing at all? I hope you can help me with this and if anyone can find another post with this question, please tell me. I am honestly quite surprised that I couldn't find a question on this topic straight away...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The documentation is actually in the **IComparable** interface page (that DateTime implements):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx

> The implementation of the CompareTo(Object) method must return an Int32 that has one of three values, as shown in the following table.
>
> **Less than zero:** The current instance precedes the object specified
> by the CompareTo method in the sort order.
>
> **Zero:** This current instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as the object specified by the CompareTo method.
>
> **Greater than zero:** This current instance follows the object specified by the CompareTo method in the sort order.

Answer (score 17):

There is nothing specified, according to MSDN:

```
if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";
```

If you want to compare days between 2 DateTimes you should be looking for something like this:

```
if ((expiryDate - DateTime.Now).Days < 30)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is an implementation detail that you should never need to know and can change at any time. The only 3 categories are:

- negative
- zero
- positive

If you find yourself using anything more than that, then something is wrong.

Comment: So that means, I cannot use it, to quickly find the difference between two times? I will have to subtract them and then look for that difference?

Comment: IMHO The fact that it's an implementation detail doesn't mean I should never need to know about it, or rather, do not **want** to know about it. The inner workings of the framework logic are interesting in themselves.

Comment: @phil13131 to find the difference between two times: subtract them to get a timespan

Comment: @Rotem Thats not what implementation detail means. Implementation detail means it can change at any time without further warning. So you shouldn't asume it will be exact values.

Comment: @Euphoric I understand that. My only claim is that the question is still interesting, despite being an implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just thought that it would make more sense if CompareTo actually returned something "more useful".

Comment: @phil13131 That would make it far less efficient as an implementation of `CompareTo`, which is used mainly for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the number is always -1, 0, or 1.

Comment: Actually there's no guarantee that -1 or 1 will be returned.

Comment: @PLB What values would you feed it to get a number other than those?

Comment: any negative or positive number, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It is implementation of [IComparable.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht.aspx). This means it will return 0 if equal, positive integer if bigger and negative integer when smaller.

Comment: (Pre-edit) The page you link to expressly says -ve, zero, +ve; ***not*** -1,0,1

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the specific units to compare with TimeSpan

`DateTime local_time = DateTime.Now;                  //current time`

`DateTime remote_time = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2);  //two minutes delayed`

`TimeSpan time_difference = (local_time - remote_time);`

`if (time_difference.Minutes <= 5)                    //compare specific units desired`

`{`

`bool within_tollerance = true;`

`}`